# What is the location of August Ferdinand Möbius' grave?

Tags: mathematics, famous-people, biography

Where is [August Ferdinand Möbius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Ferdinand_M%C3%B6bius) (17 November 1790 – 26 September 1868) buried?

He is a famous mathematician, he died in Leipzig, Germany.

I tried a search on findagrave website, but there is no entry for his name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Möbius](https://d-nb.info/gnd/119147114) died in Leipzig and was buried right there:

> August Ferdinand Möbius died in Leipzig on September 26, 1868. He was buried there in the Alten Johannisfriedhof (Old St. John's Cemetery). Today, this is a protected park, somewhat hidden behind the Grassi Museum. Möbius' former workplace, the first Leipzig University Observatory (1790–1861), which was housed in the tower of the Pleißenburg, had to make way for the New City Hall of Leipzig. The tower was demolished in 1891.
>
> — Von Klaus-Dieter Kramer: ["Landesschule Pforta: Vorgänger leitete Sternwarte"](https://www.mz.de/mitteldeutschland/burgenlandkreis/landesschule-pforta-vorganger-leitete-sternwarte-1458524), Mitteldeutsche Zeitung, 2018.

The [Grassi Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassi_Museum) has its own Wikipedia page, as does the cemetery [Old St. John's Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alter_Johannisfriedhof).

This newspaper article data is confirmed via the official 'Saxon Bibliography Database '[Saebi](https://saebi.isgv.de)'' ([PDF to his bio](https://saebi.isgv.de/files/saebi/pdf/2902_August_Moebius_(1790-1868).pdf) written by André Loh-Kliesch in 2009).